# Empty query result

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

in a web form there are two drop-down lists. The second list items should change dynamically depending on the value selected on the first drop-down list.

This is how am I trying to do it:

**index.php:**

...

```
<script>
function getClient(val) {

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_contacts.php",
    data:'client_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#contacts-list").html(data);
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

...

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mto_client" class="col-sm-2 control-label">MTO Client</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
  <select name="mto_client" id="clients_list" onChange="getClient(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a Client</option>
            <?php 
do {  
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_RSClients['id_client']?>" ><?php echo $row_RSClients['client_name']?></option>
            <?php
} while ($row_RSClients = mysql_fetch_assoc($RSClients));
?>
          </select>
      </div>
      </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mto_client_contact" class="col-sm-2 control-label">MTO Client Contact</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">

                  <select name="state" id="contacts-list">
            <option value="">Select Client Contact</option>
            </select>


      </div>
      </div>
```

**get_contacts.php**

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();

if(!empty($_POST["client_id"])) {
    $query ="SELECT * FROM tb_client_contacts WHERE contact_client_id = '" . $_POST["client_id"] . "'";
    $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
?>
    <option value="">Select Client Contact</option>
<?php
    foreach($results as $state) {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $state["id_client_contact"]; ?>"><?php echo $state["contact_name"]; ?></option>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

There are objects on the table tb_clients_contact that meet the condition, but the second drop-down list doesn't show any objects.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: 1st have a look at SQL Injection. Is it a typo that you have id_client_contact and contact_client_id?

Comment: Thanks @JRD, no these are two different fields, id_client_contact is the primary index field from tb_client_contacts, contact_client_id is another field from tb_client_contacts where tb_client_contacts stores the client from the contact.

Comment: check for errors with error reporting (and for your query) and look at your console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$("#contacts-list").html(data);
```

It should be

```
$('#contacts-list').empty().append(data);
```

`empty()` will clear first the options inside the `contacts-list` select field, then `append()` will insert the options from the result of your AJAX.

You can also look at the console log for errors. If you are using Google Chrome, hit `F12` to display the console log.